# prove matroid conditions

Tags: graph-theory, matroids

can anybody please help me to prove bicircular matroid is a matroid, from the direct definition of bicircular graph, it is also called pseudoforest.

So we define the independent set to be the edge subset of $G = (V,E)$, and each connected component of $(V,X)$ for $X$ subset of E contains at most one cycle.

Anybody has some suggestions please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: the matroid has three properties the first two of them hold trivially the third or the independent set exchange property , you must show that if the set B has less elements than A then there exists a connected component that has no cycles(otherwise the forest is maximal) then show that you can connect this component to other component by using an edge from A .

Comment: Thanks a lot for help Fayez. Though I'm still confused. I know the first two conditions are trivial, but for the 3rd one, isn't it supposed to be |X| = |Y|+1, then show Y union any edge from X-Y is still independent set? I thought of proof by contradiction, and only can think of two cases. I figured out one case, but for case 2 which has two components each contains an cycle, then add bridge in middle will violet rule for independent set, but I cannot find contradiction.

Comment: Hi @TLR. This statement of the third axiom is incorrect. If X and Y are independent sets and $|X|=|Y|+1$, then there must *exist* an element $e\in X-Y$ such that $Y\cup \{e\}$ is independent. It is not necessary that *every* element in $X-Y$ satisfies this condition. This should simplify things.